# Highcharts bar chart with fixed bar widths and gaps

Tags: highcharts

I've set

```
pointWidth: 20,
pointPadding: 0,
groupPadding: 0
```

But the chart still expands to fill the default chart height. Is it possible to have Highcharts adjust the chart height instead?

http://jsfiddle.net/MLELM/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chart will fill the available height with what you give it. 
point and group padding are a proportion of the available space, so the chart *is* honoring the properties as specified.

It uses the size of the containing element to determine its size, so it cannot possibly ignore the height of the containing element.

If you want a smaller chart that fills a larger space on your page, you can put your containing element in another wrapper element.  Then you can calculate yourself how tall your chart should be based on the number of series, and pass that height to the container.

If you want to have the series that you have specified clustered near the top, you will need to add additional null data points to fill the space below them.

If you can be more specific about what you want and why, better answers may be available.

**[[ update**

Stumbled across this post again, and remembered that I have a demo that automatically sets the chart height based on some predefined parameters, and the number of data points.

```
var barCount = chartData.length,
    pointWidth = 20,
    marginTop = 70,
    marginRight = 10,
    marginBottom = 50,
    marginLeft = 100,
    groupPadding = 0,
    pointPadding = 0.3,
    chartHeight = marginTop 
                + marginBottom 
                + ((pointWidth * barCount) 
                * (1 + groupPadding + pointPadding));
```

Fiddle here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/kpu5d1qf/

Related question here:

- [How to calculate the height of bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824305/how-to-calculate-the-height-of-bar-chart/33832694#33832694)

Comment: I simply wanted the bars to have consistent width and spacing, and have the chart adjust it's height to accommodate that, depending on the number of bars. Looks like Highcharts won't do that, but the workaround, calculating the chart height yourself, isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the chart height like that:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 200,
    },
```

See also http://jsfiddle.net/MLELM/3/

Comment: I don't want to set the chart height, but want Highcharts to adjust the chart height to whatever is needed to honor the specified pointWidth/pointPadding. Possible?

Comment: From API:By default the height is calculated from the offset height of the containing element. http://jsfiddle.net/MLELM/4/

Comment: So how can I get Highcharts to ignore the height of the containing element, and use however much vertical space it needs to honor the specified pointWidth and pointPadding?

Comment: @ejain did you ever figure this out? i am trying to get it now.

Comment: I actually just did, but its way too complex for jsfiddle. I'll link the question in a minute.