# How to calculate the height of bar chart

Tags: highcharts

How can I calculate the height of a bar chart so that for different number of bars, highcharts always use the same height for a single bar. Without setting any height the size of the bars are to large for a minor number and to thin and missing labels for larger number of bars.

Comment: Could you specify your problem? Do you want to have the same hight for every bar, independently of its value?

Comment: I talk about horizontal bar charts so the height of the bar has nothing to do with the value of the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by dynamic change of height of your chart in dependence on your data length.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.height

```
chart: {
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 80,
    height: data.length * 20 + 120 // 20px per data item plus top and bottom margins
}
```

jsFiddle made by Torstein Hønsi:
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/jMX8G/

Similar Topic: 
https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3456724-size-height-of-bar-graph-based-on-contents-when-co

You can also see custom function I wrote. Inside it I am iterating over all of my series data and making a sum of all visible data. Then I am setting the height of my chart with width of my column (passed in function parameter), number of columns, marginBottom and plotTop of my chart.

at the end if this size is different than previous size of chart I am setting new size of chart with Chart.setSize():

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/izothep/d3ezek8t/1/

Comment: Ok, I hoped for a simpler solution cause this gets really complicated when adding legends and multiple categories

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar set up that I use, I will post here for posterity:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/kpu5d1qf/

Uses a set of variables to define the chart/bar sizing parameters, and works from there.

```
//count the data points
var barCount     = chartData.length; 

//specify chart properties that will be used to calculate the total height
var pointWidth   = 20;
var marginTop    = 60;
var marginRight  = 10;
var marginBottom = 50;
var marginLeft   = 100;
var groupPadding = 0;
var pointPadding = 0.3;

var chartHeight = marginTop 
            + marginBottom 
            + ((pointWidth * barCount) * (1 + groupPadding + pointPadding));
```

And in the chart options, for example:

```
        chart: { 
            type         : 'bar', 
            marginTop    : marginTop,
            marginRight  : marginRight,
            marginBottom : marginBottom,
            marginLeft   : marginLeft,
            height       : chartHeight
        },
```

So you can edit all of the properties that might affect the height of the chart outside of the chart options, and all are accounted for when calculating the final height.